# How can I detect if a website within an iframe has the same-origin policy?

Tags: javascript, html

[image: An iframe error page that means another website, embedded in the iframe, refused to connect.]

This is an example of an error page that you would find in an iframe. I believe that the web browser embeds these pages into iframes that have content that refuses to load due to the same-origin policy that prevents certain websites such as microsoft.com from loading into an iframe. But, that still doesn't stop me from asking the community, "How can I detect if a website within an iframe has the same-origin policy?"

When Googling this exact phrase, you can't really find any duplicates of my question. Is there any basic way to detect weather or not the website in the iframe has the same-origin policy that prevents it from displaying in an iframe?

(P.S., the websites that would have that policy would not be websites owned by me, or on the same domain as my website.)

Comment: Same Origin Policy doesn't deal with iframes. It deals with HTTP requests including GET, POST, DELETE etc. To prevent iframe, sites use `X-Frame-Options` or `Content-Security-Policy: frame-ancestors`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Window.postMessage()` and please refer to this page for more help

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage

Answer (score -1):

Based on [MDN Same-origin Policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#definition_of_an_origin), the website named `http://store.company.com/dir/page.html` will be:

1. `Same-origin` if the iframe `http://store.company.com/dir2/other.html`
2. `Same-origin` if the iframe `http://store.company.com/dir/inner/another.html`
3. not `Same-origin` if the iframe `https://store.company.com/page.html` --> *Different Protocol*
4. not `Same-origin` if the iframe `http://store.company.com:81/dir/page.html` --> *Different Port*
5. not `Same-origin` if the iframe `http://news.company.com/dir/page.html` --> *Different Host*

To disable the Same-origin policy, you can try to put the header

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
```

in the server side.

Comment: This has nothing to do with ifame. The word *iframe* in the 5 points you wrote are meaningless. It is for HTTP requests, to prevent CSRF (Cross Site Request Forgery) Attacks